# Excel Print Function

Tags: excel, function, printing

I'm trying to add a print function for multiple pages with a preview.  Here is my code:

```
Sub Run_Before_Test()

Call sort_list

Call Roll_Sort

Sheets("BLACK").Select

Set oRng = Range("b11")

iRow = oRng.row
iCol = oRng.Column

Do

If Cells(iRow + 1, iCol) <> Cells(iRow, iCol) Then
Cells(iRow + 1, iCol).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
iRow = iRow + 2
Else
iRow = iRow + 1
End If
'
Loop While Not Cells(iRow, iCol).Text = ""

'Below statement will print 3 copies of the roll sheets
Function PrintMultipleSheets()
    Sheets(Array("BLACK", "1ST BROWN", "2ND BROWN", "3RD BROWN")).PrintOut From:=1, To:=1, Copies:=3, Collate:=True, Preview:=True
End Function

End Sub
```

If I put the print function before End Sub I get an error saying expected end sub, if I put it after the end sub it doesn't give me the preview.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you cannot have a function inside a sub.  Also the function does not return any thing just remove the `Function PrintMultipleSheets()` and `End Function` lines.

Comment: Thank you Scott.  That fixed it.